# Why must user input key in c++ code of Hash Table Chaining

Tags: c++, hashtable, chaining

I just need some clarification on c++ code.

According to http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-hash-tables-doubly-linked-list/ ,
I found that user need to input `value` and `key`. I can understand on why user need to input the `value` but why in the world user need to input `key`??

1) We know that the element will be located into the hash table by using hash function(eg: modulo: **element % TABLE_SIZE**). But in this code, they ask user to input which number of position in hash table they want to put their value into:

```
"Enter key at which element to be inserted: ";
```

From my understanding, user will never allowed to input their chosen position or key for their element because of an existent of hash function.

I'm so lost in this so please help me, I know there are many expert here so that's why I'm looking for the answer here

Comment: From the article I see that this is HashMap, which is used for getting values based on key. What you are looking for is, probably, HashSet.

Comment: I guess you don't understand what a map is.

Comment: Actually I want user to insert only value like this app https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/OpenHash.html . Thanks for mention about the HashMap, I don't know about that before

Answer (score 0):

In general, hashtables store *key-value pair*s.

Perhaps in your mental model there's a simplified version of a hashtable where the key is calculated based on the value?

Comment: In that case the site uses very bad wording. You don't store data "at" a key, you store it "under" a key. Basic English. In the phone book, my name is "at" page 73, but "under" the key "gnasher".

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger ;)

Answer (score 0):

The usual method is that a hash value is calculated from the key, from the hash value we calculate the preferred index into the table, plus (hopefully rarely) a sequence of alternative indexes. The hash value should be calculated in a way that it is a close as possible to random looking. The preferred index is usually just hash value modulo table size. The alternative indexes are calculated using a more or less complicated algorithm - in the most trivial case just (hash value + i) modulo table size for the i-th alternative address.

Never, ever have I seen a hash table implementation where the user or the software developer was asked to provide an alternative index.

Actually, any storage of data outside the hash table, for example in a double linked list, has really gone out of fashion. You just make the hash table big enough and the hash function good enough to avoid collisions, and if the amount of data grows then you allocate a bigger table, automatically, behind the user's back

Comment: "you just make the hash table big enough and the hash function good enough to avoid collisions" - this isn't realistic (=sane) at all.. where have you heard all this?